# How to make an infinite stream of x and sin(x) in scheme?

Tags: stream, scheme

i would like to make an infinite stream (x, f(x), f(f(x),f(f(f(x))),...) and the procedure should take x as an value and f as an procedure. I tried the following code but i don't know if it is true... how can i improve my code?

```
(define (f_stream x f) (cons-stream x (f_stream (f x) (lambda (x)
(sin x)) (f x)))) (sin x)) (f x))))

(define (f x) (sin x))
```

Answer (score 1):

What did you is close, but you put extra stuff about 'sin' into it while it should be generic. All you needed was this:

```
(define (f_stream x f) (cons-stream x (f_stream (f x) f)))
```

notice `f` is passed as a function instead of using lambda.